# How to find a string with backticks ('`') via grep?

Tags: grep, backticks

I need to grep a string from a file, which contains '`' character. How to achieve this? Wrapping string around " and ' doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give some information about the underlying operating system and shell you are using (e.g. default Ubuntu 14.04 and its "Terminal" application or whatever it is called).

Comment: \` is not an apostrophe, it's a backtick.

Comment: @melpomene Thank you for clarification english language :)

Comment: in CentOS, grep -rP and \x60 as '`' did the job.

Answer (score 0):

To grep from a file which has a backtick in its name you can put a backspace in front of it. The same works for finding a string that holds the backtick. e.g.:

```
grep \` stupid\`filename
```

Comment: Single quotes would also work: `grep '\`' 'stupid\`filename'`

Comment: That's right. Double quotes ("), however, do not work.

Comment: Thanks, however, my file was OK, I was looking for a string quoted by backtick.

Comment: @Piotr Backticks don't quote strings; they do command substitution.

Comment: @melpomene Well, you are almost correct. However, if you have simple text file than this statement doesn't apply. Ie. in mysql dump file you have tables names wrapped by backticks.